# Cross-Origin Request Blocked even after adding headers in server code

Tags: node.js, angular, express

I've a simple API in Express/Node and I also have a simple angular application for posting blogs. The only problem is when I hit the `/contribute` route using POST method. I'm getting this error on both chrome and firefox:

> error: error { target: XMLHttpRequest, isTrusted: true, lengthComputable: false, … }
> ​
> headers: Object { normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, headers: Map(0) }
> ​
> message: "Http failure response for localhost:3000/api/contribute: 0 Unknown Error"
> ​
> name: "HttpErrorResponse"
> ​
> ok: false
> ​
> status: 0
> ​
> statusText: "Unknown Error"
> ​
> url: "localhost:3000/api/contribute"
> ​
> : {…}
> ​​
> constructor: class HttpErrorResponse { constructor(init) }​​
> : {…}
> ​​​
> constructor: class HttpResponseBase { constructor(init, defaultStatus, defaultStatusText) }​​​
> : {…

Here's my server side code.

**api.js**

```
...
router.post('/contribute', (req, res) => {
    console.log('Pushing new article');
    let userPost = req.body;
    let post = new Post(userPost);
    post.save((error, registeredPost) => {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        } else {
            res.status(200).send(registeredPost);
        }
    })
})
...
module.exports = router;
```

**server.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();

const api = require('./routes/api');
const cors = require('cors');

app.use(bodyParser.json());

// app.use(cors({ origin: 'http://localhost:4200' })); <--- TRIED THIS ALSO

app.use(function (req, res, next) {

    // Website you wish to allow to connect
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:4200');

    // Request methods you wish to allow
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');

    // Request headers you wish to allow
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');

    // Set to true if you need the website to include cookies in the requests sent
    // to the API (e.g. in case you use sessions)
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);

    // Pass to next layer of middleware
    next();
});

app.use('/api', api);
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send('Server is up and running!');
})

app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log('Server listening port:3000');
});
```

Yes, server is up and running.

Here is angular code.
**auth.service.ts**

```
private _contributeUrl = "https://localhost:3000/api/contribute";
...
pushNewPost(newPost) {
  console.log("here is the new post", newPost); // GETTING CORRECT OUTPUT
  return this._http.post<any>(this._contributeUrl, newPost);
}
```

**contribute.component.ts**

```
this._auth.pushNewPost(this.makeNewPost)
.subscribe (
  res => {
    (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("inputTitle")).value="";
    this.editorForm.reset();
    this.addSingle();
  },
  err => console.log(err)
);
```

Now the fun part is that the same code is working perfectly when I make a post request to this route using Postman without any error.

Please correct my mistake. After adding:

```
  pushNewPost(newPost) {
    console.log("here is the new post", newPost);
    let headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
     });
     let options = { headers: headers };
    return this._http.post<any>(this._contributeUrl, newPost);
  }
```

I'm getting this:

[image]

Comment: Should it not be just **http** instead of *https* for local API in `private _contributeUrl = "https://localhost:3000/api/contribute";`?

Comment: Sure @NicholasK, actually it is still under review by my tech lead. But it is working so I'm accepting it now. Sorry for the delay. My apologies.

Comment: @NicholasK, actually in real case my api is not running on localhost. Just to diagnose the error I pulled that branch in my local. The actual server is deployed here.https://obscure-tundra-38074.herokuapp.com
Its running you can cross check

Comment: @NicholasK, the moment i change `private _contributeUrl = "https://obscure-tundra-38074.herokuapp.com/api/contribute";` I start getting the same error.

Comment: HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 500, statusText: "Internal Server Error", url: "http://obscure-tundra-38074.herokuapp.com/api/contribute", ok: false, …}

Comment: Thank you. From the http status 500, it indicates that there is a problem with the server side code. Could you check the logs and confirm? Also, are you able to hit the API using the correct url i.e `obscure...../contribute` from POSTMAN?

Comment: this message: "Http failure response for https://obscure-tundra-38074.herokuapp.com/api/contribute: 500 Internal Server Error"

Comment: I wonder why this works perfectly with Postman. I mean when i try to post it through postman using JSON.

Comment: In server logs you can see the exact error message too i.e. why it failed with 500

Comment: Also, are you able to hit the API using the correct url i.e `obscure...../contribute` from POSTMAN?

Comment: With Postman I'm able to hit both `obscure...` and `localhost`. That's why I'm more confused.

Comment: Server log is clean.

Comment: Is a zoom call possible ? I'm blocked since 1 week.

Comment: Sorry, no. What does `newPost` hold and what are the headers you are passing from POSTMAN?

Comment: newPost is just a json with `{
    "articleid": "q2w3eyt4r5t",
    "title":"Installing ReactJS on Linux 18.04 with command line.",
    "content" :"<strong>fork</strong>",
    "date":"Mon, 07 Oct 2019 18:08:34 GMT",
    "contributor":"Tanzeel Mirza"
}}`

Comment: and I'm not passing any headers in Postman. Only content-type it says application/json

Comment: You need to pass in the content-type headers too from angular

Comment: oh. How can i do that. Plz guide

Comment: Included an answer. Let me know if it works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225859/discussion-between-tanzeel-and-nicholas-k).

Comment: Chat is blocked for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you are not sending in the headers from angular. Make the following changes:

```
pushNewPost(newPost) {
  // adding the headers
  const headers = new HttpHeaders({
   'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  });
  const options = { headers: headers };

  return this._http.post<any>(this._contributeUrl, newPost, options);
}
```

Comment: I'm adding a screenshot in question.

Comment: Seems, more like a backend issue to me.

Comment: Ok. give me some time. Let me explore more about this. I'll get back to you. And please feel free to remind me about this open question. :-)

Comment: Hi Nicholas, I figured out something on my own. First thing first, in ***server.js** I changed this `res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:4200');` to `res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');`. then I also realized I made a very stupid mistake. I forgot to pass `option` in `... return this._http.post<any>(this._contributeUrl, newPost, options);`. So now code is working. But I wonder if i have to pass headers with every other request as I've at least 15 different calls like update, delete, upvote, downvote, duplicate, etc. Please guide me.

Comment: In this case I'm making `headers` and `options` global and passing it as `return this._http.post<any>(..., ..., this.options);` Is this approach correct ?

Comment: Oh that's great! Typically, you would have an interceptor and you would pass headers from there rather than for every http call.

Comment: aaaahhh...now i understand the purpose of interceptor. Actually I've a token-interceptor service already. Anyway, pushed to branch, raising the pull request now. :-) thanks